# Best way to get result from an AsyncTask to the caller class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have implemented a way of getting the result from `onPostExecute` back to my main activity. I wanted to know if this is the right thing I did, is there any more chance of improving it, and if it's not the best way, what is the best way?

This is what I have done:

```
public class MainClass implements AsyncResponse {
    private MyAsyncTask asyncTask;

    public MainClass() {
        asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
        asyncTask.asyncResponse = this;
    }

    public void startTask( {
        asyncTask.execute("string");
    }

    @Override
    public void processDone(String res) {
        // got response in MainClass from onPostExecute
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected AsyncResponse asyncResponse = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return "some processed string";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String res) {
            this.asyncResponse.processDone(res);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the `AsyncResponse` interface:

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processDone(String res);
}
```

I want to know in terms of processing speed that on an average android mobile device, would this be a good approach and if not, how do I improve it to make it a good approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I always done this way and never had any issues. I would say it is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

in one Line without any callback

```
   String s= new MyAsyncTask().execute().get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You added an unnecessary interface - and perhaps it makes your code less usable.

First, if you create the `AsyncTask` as a class within your `Activity` there is no need for the interface. You can simply do this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String res) {
    processDone(res);
}
```

The `AsyncTask` will execute `onPostExecute` on the UI thread and you can call the `Activity` method without the interface.

Second, if you create `AsyncTask` outside the `Activity` class (for example, in its own java file) then you can use this method, except it is not a good idea because it will hold a reference to the `Activity` on another thread - it's a memory leak risk.

To avoid that, your interface should be implemented in a separate class, like `AsyncTaskResponse.java` that is passed to the `AsyncTask` class.

Last, `AsyncTask` provides the response in the form of a `String` if that is sufficient. You should look at the docs on `AsyncTask`:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: But I could just make it reusable by separating the asynctask class and use it in other classes. Then I would have to have an interface right?

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping the `AsyncTask` inside another POJO class; doing this doesn't hurt, but provides little benefit.

Consider that when the task is completed, you will want a callback notification somewhere.  Your `MainClass` will get a callback in `processDone()`, but something will need to be listening to `MainClass` to get that notification.

Here is a pattern I always use with my `AsyncTask` subclasses:

```
public class GetDataRemoteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Data> {

    private static final String TAG = "GetDataRemoteTask ";

    private WeakReference<GetDataResultListener> mListenerRef;

    private Exception mExc;

    @Override
    protected Data doInBackground(String... params) {

        Data result = null;

        try {
            result = mService.getData(params[0], params[1], params[2]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred getting data", e);
            mExc = e;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Data result) {

        if (mListenerRef != null) {
            GetDataResultListener listener = mListenerRef.get();
            if (listener != null) {
                if (mExc == null) { 
                    listener.dataReceived(result);
                } else {
                    listener.dataException(mExc);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setGetDataResultListener(GetDataResultListener listener) {

        if (listener == null) {
            this.mListenerRef = null;
        } else {
            this.mListenerRef = new WeakReference<GetDataResultListener >(listener);
        }
    }

    public static interface GetDataResultListener {

        public void dataReceived(Data data);

        public void dataException(Exception exc);
    }

}
```

So to start off, here I have an interface, like you do, for connecting to the `AsyncTask`.  But I don't wrap my `AsyncTask` with an implementation, I expect that I will have an `Activity` or a `Fragment` that will implement this interface.  (That's why I use a `WeakReference`; if the `Activity` finishes, my `AsyncTask` won't keep holding on to the `Activity`.  But that also means I can't use an anonymous class listener unless the client holds the reference for it.)

My client code will look like this:

```
        GetDataRemoteTask task = new GetDataRemoteTask();
        task.setListener(this);
        task.execute(param1, param2, param3);
```

I also have a way to find out if there was an exception that occurred in the background task.  Any background exceptions should always be reported to the client, which can decide how best to deal with the exception - for example pop up a dialog for the user, so they know the request failed.

I think that a big drawback of `AsyncTask` is that it doesn't have more structure around handling exceptions that occur in the background thread.

My task holds a reference to the exception, but I have also used `Pair<Data, Exception>` as a type parameter for return result so I don't need the exception property.

Using this pattern has helped me avoid some typical problems that occur when coding `AsyncTask` subclasses.